# Combining tsvectors from multiple rows into one

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table with a text field and a `tsvector` containing the search index for that field:

```
CREATE TABLE test (pk bigint, value text, tsv tsvector);
```

How do I create a single `tsvector` that is the combination of the vectors for all rows satisfying some condition?

```
SELECT value FROM test
WHERE combine_my_vectors(SELECT tsv FROM test WHERE pk IN (some list))
      @@ to_tsquery('search me');
```

I know that `tsvector`s can be combined with `||`, but that doesn't seem to be possible here. What do I use for `combine_my_vectors`?

I would prefer to avoid having to combine my `value` text fields first, and then create a `tsvector` out of them.

Comment: What is the point of that? You'd have to create your own aggregate function.

Comment: The point is that the resulting vector is used as a part of a larger one, and the system cares that only one result is returned (as opposed to one result per row)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If there's a better way to achieve that though, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nice thing about PostgreSQL is that it is so extensible.

You can simply define your own aggregate for this:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE tsvector_agg(tsvector) (
   STYPE = pg_catalog.tsvector,
   SFUNC = pg_catalog.tsvector_concat,
   INITCOND = ''
);
```

You can use it like this:

```
SELECT tsvector_agg(tsv) FROM test;
```

Of course you cannot use a full text search index for this, because the matched value will not belong to a single row.